# How to disable other Apps or other apps communication with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

I am looking for information on how to disable/enable other apps with Ionic. Or even block the network communication of another app through a button in my ionic app.

Is this possible with Ionic? What plugins or tools should I look for?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such privileges in general are reserved with the system (operating system) and each app including ionic-cordova hybrid would run in a "sandbox" and app 2 app APIs are normally not common or not available/exposed.

There was an attempt to do app2app API with windows phone but failed.

So at best you could try leverage app specific schemas to let OS know you want external app to do something. But definitely you can't control other app's behavior like you described (was possible in early days of Android actually I think)

Comment: What about network control? For example, block the device's network communication in a given protocol. Was it the same situation?

Comment: No those are system leverage priviledges and non of mobile platform SDKs offers such ability afaik. You can monitor network (like app can know if its online) but thats about it. It doesn't have a right to turn airplane mode etc. It is a system level priviledge